# Adding extension attribute to customer rest API giving Fatal error

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, rest-api

I'm trying to add custom extension_attribute to customer API (REST) in Magento 2.
The logic is working for single record API `V1/customers/{{CUSTOEMR_ID}}`
But it is not working for search API `V1/customers/search?searchCriteria`
For search API I'm getting follwing error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Customer\MyCustomerRepository: :afterGetList() must be an instance of Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerSearchResultsInterfaceFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146 and defined in /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Extension/Plugin/Customer/MyCustomerRepository.php: 57
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Customer\MyCustomerRepository-&gt;afterGetList(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults), Object(Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor-&gt;Magento\Framework\Int in /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Extension/Plugin/Customer/MyCustomerRepository.php on line 57
```

Following are the used files

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository">       
        <plugin name="Vendor_Extension::MyCustomerRepository" type="\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Customer\MyCustomerRepository"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="reward_points_balance" type="float"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**MyCustomerRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface as CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerSearchResultsInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class MyCustomerRepository
{
    private $extensionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory = null
    ) {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ExtensionAttributesFactory::class);
    }

    public function afterGetById(CustomerRepository $subject, CustomerInterface $customer)
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
            /** @var CustomerExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes */
            $extensionAttributes = $this->extensionFactory->create(CustomerInterface::class);
            $customer->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }
        if ($extensionAttributes->getRewardPointsBalance() === null) {
            $fRewardPoints = $this->getRewardPoints($customer);
            $extensionAttributes->setRewardPointsBalance($fRewardPoints);
        }
        return $customer;
    }

    public function afterGetList(CustomerRepository $subject, CustomerSearchResultsInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $customers = $searchResult->getItems();

        foreach($customers as $customer)
        {
            $extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
            if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
                /** @var CustomerExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes */
                $extensionAttributes = $this->extensionFactory->create(CustomerInterface::class);
                $customer->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
            }
            if ($extensionAttributes->getRewardPointsBalance() === null) {
                $fRewardPoints = $this->getRewardPoints($customer);
                $extensionAttributes->setRewardPointsBalance($fRewardPoints);
            }
        }


        return $searchResult;
    }

    private function getRewardPoints(CustomerInterface $customer)
    {
        $customerId = $customer->getId();

        $fCustomerRewardPoints = 10.00;

        return $fCustomerRewardPoints;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to pass the instance of `CustomerSearchResultsInterface`, not the interface. `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults` is the instance of the interface. But, it's safe if you don't set the instance of `$result`.

Changes your plugin:

```
public function afterGetList(CustomerRepository $subject, \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults $results) {
    ......
}
```

Or

```
public function afterGetList(CustomerRepository $subject, $results) {
    ......
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Khoa, it worked!